# Public visibility of Git repo using command line

Tags: ruby, git, github, gitlab

I had a ruby's script to create a Git repository using command line (and GitLab API), also it could realize commit and push, but my problem is the created repo had a visibility private so how I can change the visibilty?

And how can I add the created repository to a group using commands line?

This my script in Github: https://github.com/ivanove/my_works/blob/master/Create-Repo.rb

This is `create_repo` method from it:

```
def crete_repo(name)
  puts "Creating Git repository #{name}...".blue
  cmd = "curl -H \"Content-Type:application/json\" http://#{@host}/api/v3/projects?private_token=#{@token} -d '{\"name\":\"#{name}\"}'"
  puts cmd
  system(cmd)
  puts "done."
end
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code *directly* in your question (use the **edit** link). This is a requirement on Stack Overflow. Also your README says your script is for Git*Lab*, not Git*Hub*. Please be clear about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `visibility_level = 20` to your request parameters (see [documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#create-project)). That would be in your `create_repo` method.

Also, consider using GitLab client instead of running curl from command line. For example, [this one](https://github.com/NARKOZ/gitlab).

Comment: my code can create only repository of a user, so how I can create a repository for a groups using an exisiting namesapce ?, even I add **namespace_id (optional) - namespace for the new project (defaults to user)** but it doesn't work, this is my new code :
cmd="curl -H \"Content-Type:application/json\" http://#{@host}/api/v3/projects?private_token=#{@token} -d '{\"name\":\"#{name}\",\"visibility_level\": 20 , \"namespace_id \":\"group-from-1\"}'"

Comment: Hey @Euphor08! It's better to make a new post with your question.